# py4j error "An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.init."

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I was trying to do a aws glue spark job to read some data from a table to S3 location .
But i was getting an error as below stack trace as "An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.init." Can anyone suggest a way how to debug this issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\inbound_db.py", line 31, in <module>
    glue_spark.job.init(
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\awsglue\job.py", line 42, in init
    self._job.init(job_name, self._glue_context._glue_scala_context, args)
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.init.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigMergeable
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job$.init(Job.scala:96)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.init(Job.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigMergeable
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 14 more

23/11/14 22:12:22 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
23/11/14 22:12:22 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it
Whole idea is that jars in /opt/spark/jars and ./aws-glue-libs/jarsv1 should match. i copied the jars in both folders to make it identical and the issue gone away